# React-Naitve-video show error like "RCTvideo is not fabric compatible yet! " for Android emulator & device

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fabric, react-native-video, new-architecture

In React-Native I'm using React-native-video npm for play video from URL.
It's working perfectly in iOS , but in Android I facing this type of issue.
LIke: **"RCTvideo is not fabric compatible yet! "**

I checked the this [MR-2650](https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video/issues/2650), [Issue-2](https://https:/https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video/issues/3120).
But still facing same issue.

According to react-native [new architecture](https://github.com/reactwg/react-native-new-architecture/discussions/135) , I tried to add in react-native-config.js. But still facing same issue.